# hibernate auto flush incorrect?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 4.3.10.Final, mysql 5.6.

for flush mode, the default is 'Auto', right?
And in this case, if there are steps about persist A, select B, commit, then hibernate should execute select B first, then persist A, right?

(I got this understanding base on https://dzone.com/articles/dark-side-hibernate-auto-flush, or do I misunderstand this article?)

If my understanding is right, why my following code shows different result(I don't set flush mode manually) :

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {       
    try {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
        return config.buildSessionFactory(registry);

    }catch(Throwable ex) {          
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

```
factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
s = factory.openSession();

s.beginTransaction();
Student a = new Student();
a.setAge(30);
a.setName("test");
s.persist(a);

Query query = s.createQuery("from Address");        
List<Address> list = query.list();
for(Address addr : list) {
    System.out.println(addr.getId()+", "+addr.getZipCode());
}
        
s.getTransaction().commit();
s.close();
factory.close();
```

the 'Student' looks like :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

and the id of Address also is GenerationType.AUTO too.

my hibernate configuration file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>    
    <session-factory>       
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"/>        
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>        
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>        
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>        
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        
        <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">resources/ehcache.xml</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>       
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        
        <mapping class="com.my.hibernate.basic.Student" />      
        <mapping class="com.my.hibernate.basic.Address" />      
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

then why hibernate statements of above code are as follows :

> Hibernate: insert into Student (age, name) values (?, ?)
>
> Hibernate: select address0_.id as id1_0_, address0_.zipCode as
> zipCode2_0_ from Address address0_

doesn't it should be : select Address first then insert into Student because I use 'auto' flush mode and these 2 statements are dependent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the article says: ""As stated in the reference documentation, the AUTO flush strategy may sometimessynchronize the current persistence context prior to a query execution""

Comment: @RenéWinkler but according to the examples at the end of this article, it seems that my example should be execute select first, then insert.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

6.1. AUTO flush

> By default, Hibernate uses the AUTO flush mode which triggers a flush
>   in the following circumstances:
>
> - prior to committing a Transaction
> - prior to executing a JPQL/HQL query that overlaps with the queued
>     entity actions
> - before executing any native SQL query that has no registered
>     synchronization

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-auto

So in your case point 2 is true because you say these two statements are dependent. (I assume you mean that Address is related to student)